# How can I run a pattern rule within another rule in a makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am looking to write a makefile to automate the compiling of a project that I am working on where the files may, or may not, change in number. I also need to be able to quickly tell make to compile the files as a debug build or a release build (differentiated by a command line define). After some research, I came upon pattern rules and made one. Here is the code I have so far:

```
# Our folders
# ODIR -    The .o file directory
# CDIR -    The .cpp file directory
# HDIR -    The .hpp file directory
ODIR = obj
CDIR = src
HDIR = inc

# Get our compiler and compiler commands out of the way
# CC -  Our compiler
# CFNO - Our compiler flags for when we don't have an output file
# CF -  Our compiler flags. This should be appended to any compile and should
#           have the name of the output file at the end of it.
# OF -  Object flags. This should be appended to any line that is generating
#           a .o file. 
CC = g++
CFNO = -std=c++11 -wall -Wno-write-strings -Wno-sign-compare -lpaho-mqtt3c -pthread -O2 -I$(HDIR)
CF = $(CFNO) -o
OF = -c

# Our project/output name
NAME = tls_test

# Set out Debug and Release settings, as well as any defines we will use to identify which mode we are in
# NOTE: '-D[NAME OF DEFINE]' is how you create a define through the compile commands
DEBUG = -DDEBUG -g
RELEASE = -DRELEASE

# Our two compile modes
# eval allows us to create variables mid-rule
debug:
    $(eval DR = $(DEBUG))

release:
    $(eval DR = $(RELEASE))

# Our compiling commands
all: 
    $(CC) $(CF) $(NAME) $(ODIR)/*.o

# NOTE: $@ is the end product being created and $< is the first of the prerequisite
$(ODIR)/%.o: $(CDIR)/%.c
    echo "$(CC) $(DR) $(OF) $(CF) $@ $<"
```

The issue that I am having is with the order that I need things to run in. The command line call should tell make to use either debug or release, which sets a make variable, then call all. all should then run the pattern rule at the bottom before running the line currently in the all rule. So, how do I make a pattern rule a dependency and how do I call a rule from another rule?

Comment: You want Make to compile all of the source files in `src/` (with flags appropriate to the build), then link all of the resultant object files into an executable, is that right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use target-specific variables

While not strictly necessary, separating your flags goes a long way in managing build options, you can then use [target-specific variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific) appends to toggle the flags. While you're at it you might as well use the built-in variable names.

I've also added dependency generation (`-MMD -MP`) because it's always useful.

```
ODIR := obj
CDIR := src
HDIR := inc

SRCS := $(wildcard $(CDIR)/*.cpp)
OBJS := $(SRCS:$(CDIR)/%.cpp=$(ODIR)/%.o)
DEPS := $(OBJS:%.o=%.d)

CPPFLAGS := -I$(HDIR) -MMD -MP
CXXFLAGS := -std=c++11 -Wall -Wno-write-strings -Wno-sign-compare -pthread -O2
LDFLAGS  := -pthread
LDLIBS   := -lpaho-mqtt3c

NAME := tls_test

.PHONY: debug release clean

debug: CPPFLAGS+=-DDEBUG
debug: CXXFLAGS+=-g

release: CPPFLAGS+=-DRELEASE

debug release: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

$(OBJS): $(ODIR)/%.o: $(CDIR)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<

clean: ; $(RM) $(NAME) $(OBJS) $(DEPS)    

-include $(DEPS)
```

Comment: I can guess what you intended `OUTPUT_OPTION` to be, but you should probably spell it out.

Comment: @Beta Why, make defaults it to `-o $@`.

Comment: I stand corrected. I hadn't known about that variable, but now that I do, I don't see that it makes this makefile any easier to understand or maintain.

Comment: @Beta Perhaps not, but that's what the built-in rule uses so I thought it might as well be left in there, although I've never used compilers that don't support `-o`.

Comment: This won't recompile the objects if OP runs `make debug` and then `make release` back-to-back though (unless the gcc dependency generation is smarter than I think it is at this point).

Comment: @EtanReisner No it certainly won't, personally I work around that by writing makefiles that recreate the source tree outside the root kind of like how autotools work, but `make clean` would work fine in this case. Any other suggestions for this kind of thing?

Comment: You can manually handle it with differing output directories or by keeping stamp files of the build flags in use but they have their own issues and complications. I mostly just wanted to make sure it was mentioned as a potential issue. Since a lot of people try to do this and don't realize it doesn't work the way they want and then come back and ask about it (there are a number of questions about this on here already).

Comment: @EtanReisner I hadn't thought about that even though I'm pretty sure I was caught in the same trap when learning make.